# Not able to create Calabash step definition for scenario

Tags: ui-automation, calabash, calabash-android

I'm new to Calabash and trying to create Steps definition for below the feature file with respective scenarios (QA looks like a possible duplicate but no answer found in SOF) How to generate the step definition using UIAutomator viewer tool. error screenshot attached for ref[image] Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

```
Feature: Valid Login 

Scenario: Login with valid mobile number
    When I see "Login/Signup" screen
    And  I enter "72046606**" in "etMobilNumber" text field 
    And  I click on "Login/Signup" button
    And  I enter "WebDriver12" in "etPassword" text field
    And  I click on "Login" button
    And  I wait
    Then I see "Enter mPIN" screen 


Scenario: Login with valid mPIN
    When I see "Enter mPIN" screen
    And  I click on "2" button
    And  I click on "3" button
    And  I click on "6" button
    And  I click on "9" button
    And  I wait
    Then I see "J****" text 


Scenario: Launch Money Transfer screen
    When I see "J*****" screen
    And  I click on "MoneyTransfer" button
    And  I click on "Send Money" text
    And  I wait
    Then I see "Send Money" text
```

Comment: Could you share your step definition? If you have not already please refer to Github https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android or to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/introduction-to-calabash/

Comment: I have asked for Step definition only, Anyhow I found answers for it. thanks

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted it out, you should consider adding your own answer then it might help someone else later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature file:

```
 Feature: Login

 Scenario: I should login via valid credentials
    When I enter mobile number "7204660611" into mobile number input field with "ID" 
    Then I see "Login/Signup" button as enable
    And I tap "Login/Signup" button
    Then I wait 60 seconds
    Then I see "Password" field
    And I enter Password "WebDriver12" input Password input field with "ID"
    Then I tap "Login" button
    Then I should get new page
```

Step Definition:

```
require 'calabash-android/calabash_steps'

When(/^I enter mobile number "([^"]*)" into mobile number input field with "([^"]*)"$/) do |mobileNumber, etMobileNumber|
 enter_text("* marked:'etMobileNumber'","***34*****")
end

Then(/^I see "([^"]*)" button as enable$/) do |arg1|
 if query("* marked:'btnSignin'",:enabled).first.eql?true
  else
    raise "FAILED!!! Invalid Mobile number"
 end
end

Then(/^I tap "([^"]*)" button$/) do |arg1|
  touch("* marked:'btnSignin'")
end

Then(/^I wait (\d+) seconds$/) do |arg1|
  wait_for_element_exists("* marked:'etPassword'")
end

Then(/^I see "([^"]*)" field$/) do |arg1|
  if query("* marked:'etPassword'",:enabled).first.eql?true
  else
   fail "Failed!! Password field not present"
  end
 end

 Then(/^I enter Password "([^"]*)" input Password input field with "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg1, arg2|
  enter_text("* marked:'etPassword'","WebD*****")
 end

Then(/^I should get new page$/) do
   wait_for_element_exists("* marked:'Enter mPIN'")
end
```